# Does CodeShip support multi-/cross-container testing?

Tags: codeship

I'm looking for a CI solution that allows me to do acceptance testing across my app's multiple container-based services.  Does CodeShip support that?

I have put in a request to discuss this with their sales dept but their documentation led me to believe this was a better place for the question.

Comment: Are your services in separate repos? Are you pushing containers to a registry?

Comment: Separate repos, yes.  Pushing to containers, yes.

Comment: *Pushing to a registry, yes.  (typo)

Comment: I will write a solution idea, but know this may get flagged since it's not about programming specifically. :(

Comment: I think it's doable, but not sure it will be automatic.